# New to C++ : trying to learn separate interface from Implementation and got error : invalid operands to binary expression in VSCode

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am learning about **separate interface from implementation** in C++ and got this error.

Searched for it but din't understood how I should implement this in my code.This is my code.

InvoiceClass.h:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class InvoiceClass{
    private:
        int price;
        int quantity;
        string partName;
        string partDescription;

    public:
        InvoiceClass(string, string, int, int);
        void displayInvoice();
        void setDetail(string, string, int, int);
};
```

InvoiceClass.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"InvoiceClass.h"
using namespace std;

// Constructor function.
InvoiceClass::InvoiceClass(string partName, string partDescription, int qty, int price){
    price = price;
    quantity = qty;
    partName = partName;
    partDescription = partDescription;
}

void InvoiceClass::setDetail(string partName, string partDescription, int qty, int price){
    price = price;
    quantity = qty;
    partName = partName;
    partDescription = partDescription;
}

void InvoiceClass::displayInvoice(){
    cout<<"Invoice"<<endl;
    cout<<"Item    "<<"Desc      "<<"QTY      "<<"Price"<<endl;
    cout<<partName<<"     "<<partDescription<<"     "<<quantity<<"     "<<price<<endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"InvoiceClass.h"
using namespace std;

// Main function
int main(){
    InvoiceClass customer("iMac", "By Apple", 1, 219000);

    cout<<customer.displayInvoice()<<endl;
}
```

It should print the output of displayInvoice().
Please help me.

Comment: `void displayInvoice();` doesn't return any value but writes to `std::cout` directly. You just write `customer.displayInvoice();` that's enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you function doesn't return so when you do

```
 cout<<customer.displayInvoice()
```

you basically say show what my function returns which it doesn't i assume you wanted to do

```
int main(){
    InvoiceClass customer("iMac", "By Apple", 1, 219000);

    customer.displayInvoice();
}
```

Plus :  In your constructor

The compiler is confusing between the "price" in your constructor input with the variable price of your class same with others variable so you have to use "this" to eliminate this confusion

```
 InvoiceClass::InvoiceClass(string partName, string partDescription, int qty,  int price) {
    this->price = price;
    quantity = qty;
    this->partName = partName;
    this->partDescription = partDescription;
}
```

Same problem in the setDetail function